# Drupal Theming and custom variables in custom pages

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming, preprocessor

I have created a custom page which sits at site.com/user/me/soe

now im trying to theme this page and have created a subsequent template file.

however if i copy in any basic html into my template file, all it does is produce a white page with my text and abandons the sites structure i originally had.

i was hoping somebody could help me understand preprocessing as i feel that is the way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like want to override the template for just the node content, and not the entire page.

For example:

page-node-10.tpl.php will override the template for the entire page for node 10

node-10.tpl.php will override the template for just the content of node 10, and render inside of the default page.tpl.php template